# Writing a function that is summing up certain values in a row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I would like to write a function that helps me to sum up every negative values as i.e. result1, and every positive values as result2. So basically, this function should iterate over the column "total_load"

[image: example of the dataframe]

```
def total_battery(ok6, col_name='total_load'):
"""Return a dictionary with counts of occurrences."""

   
# Initialize an empty dictionary: cols_values
cols_values = {}

# Extract column from df: col
col = ok6[col_name]

# iterate over the column in df
for entry in col:


    if entry in cols_values.keys() < 0: ***--> then sum all the negative values*** 
        cols_values[entry] += sum
    
    else: 
        if entry in cols_values.keys() > 0: ***--> then sum all the negative values*** 
            cols_values[entry] += sum


    # Return the cols_count dictionary
    return cols_values

# Call count_entries(): result1
result1 = total_battery(ok6, "total_load")

# Call count_entries(): result2
result2 = total_battery(ok6, "total_load")

# Print result1 and result2
print(result1)
print(result2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering and then [`Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
result1 = df.loc[df['total_load'] < 0, 'total_load'].sum()
result2 = df.loc[df['total_load'] > 0, 'total_load'].sum()
```

---

```
result1 = df.query('total_load < 0')['total_load'].sum()
result2 = df.query('total_load > 0')['total_load'].sum()
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', periods=4, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'total_load':[1,2,-3,-5]}, index=rng)
print (df)
                     total_load
2016-06-01 00:00:00           1
2016-06-01 00:01:00           2
2016-06-01 00:02:00          -3
2016-06-01 00:03:00          -5

result1 = df.loc[df['total_load'] < 0, 'total_load'].sum()
result2 = df.loc[df['total_load'] > 0, 'total_load'].sum()
print (result1)
-8
print (result2)
3

result1 = df.query('total_load < 0')['total_load'].sum()
result2 = df.query('total_load > 0')['total_load'].sum()
print (result1)
-8
print (result2)
3
```

Comment: That's great and a lot more easier^^ Thank you jezrael!

Comment: Yes. I first use pure python for data analyse too, but  for better performance I start use pandas. It was very good decision :) Good luck!